# What do we know about the semigroup $e^{it\sqrt{-\Delta}}$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

I am very interested in the properties of the semigroup $e^{it\sqrt{-\Delta}}$, which may has some fundamental differences (such as the kernel) with the well-known Schrödinger semigroup  $e^{it\Delta}$.

Any properties (or references or books) that related this semigroup are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try putting "heat semigroup" in google and you'll get lots relevant references.

Comment: I think no-one has mentioned yet that $e^{it\sqrt{-\Delta}}$ has an explicit kernel $c_n (-it) (|x|^2 - t^2 - 0i)^{-(n+1)/2}$, where $n$ is the dimension and $c_n$ is an appropriate constant. The kernel is singular around $|x|=t$. In particular, in dimension $n = 1$, the kernel is simply $$\operatorname{p.v.} \biggl(\frac{1}{\pi} \, \frac{-it}{x^2 - t^2}\biggr) + \frac{1}{2} (\delta_t(x) + \delta_{-t}(x)).$$

Comment: Also, the operator $\sqrt{-\Delta}$ is sometimes called the (quasi-)relativistic Hamiltonian for a massless particle, and has been studied heavily by, for example, Lieb and co-authors.

Answer (score 9):

The wave operator decomposes as
$$
\partial_t^2-\Delta = (\partial_t-i\sqrt{-\Delta})(\partial_t+i\sqrt{-\Delta}),
$$
so you can think of $e^{it\sqrt{-\Delta}}$ as solving a "half of" the wave equation. The dispersion relation is $\omega = |\xi|$, where $\omega$ and $\xi$ are the Fourier variables for $t$ and $x$, respectively. On the other hand, the Schrödinger propagator $e^{it\Delta}$ has the dispersions relation $\omega=|\xi|^2$, which makes it genuinely dispersive, i.e., the propagation speed depends on the frequency.

Note that $e^{it\Delta}$ is *not* the heat semigroup, which the other answers and comments seem to suggest.

Comment: The downvoter care to comment?

Comment: You're right, $e^{it\Delta}$ isn't the heat semigroup. Editing my answer.


Comment: It is not actually true that this operator has a finite speed of propagation. Finite speed = compactly supported kernel = entire analytic symbol (by Paley-Wiener). The symbol $e^{it|\xi|}$ is not entire analytic

Comment: Note that the wave equation has entire symbol, indeed it is $\cos(t|\xi|)$ plus $\sin(t|\xi|)|\xi|^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

You can say a lot about the function $u(t,x)=e^{it\sqrt{-\Delta}}f$ by noticing, as remarked by others, that $u$ is also solution of the Cauchy problem
$$
u_{tt}-\Delta u=0,\quad
u(0,x)=f,\quad
u_t(0,x)=i\sqrt{-\Delta}f.
$$
Thus most estimates for solutions of the wave equation carry over to $u$. However there are some subtle differences, mostly due to the non--locality of the operator $\sqrt{-\Delta}$.